# nested Concatenation of strings into another string after a particular word

Tags: javascript, jquery

"str" is a string in which i need to concate another string bw "InsertAfterMe" and "InsertBeforeMe".

```
str="This is a string InsertAfterMe InsertBeforeMe"

s1="sometext"
s2="soMoreText" 
aList=[1,2,3,4,5]
```

String which needs to be concatenated is "s1+aListValue+s2"
These will repeat according to the no of elements in the list.
eg. if there are 2 elements in the list,i.e 1,2
then my output should be

```
"This is a string InsertAfterMe sometext 1 someMoreText sometext 2 someMoreText InsertbeforeMe"
```

I cannot judge or find the index of the position where "insertAfterMe" word as str could be dynamic.

Please help me resolve this.
I tried getting the index by searching the word after which i need to concate but it could not help with the list part.

Comment: Can you please show what you have attempted to solve this homework question so far.

Comment: You only need to insert into the original string once. By which you find the insert location with `indexOf`. You can build the string you are inserting using a loop... try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
str = "This is a string InsertAfterMe InsertBeforeMe"

s1 = "sometext"
s2 = "soMoreText"
aList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

var toAppend = s1 + " " + aList.join(" "+s2+" "+s1+" ") + " " +s2;

str = str.replace(/InsertAfterMe/g, "InsertAfterMe " + toAppend);
alert(str);
```

Comment: Thnak you so much for so quick reply.Can you please explain this str = str.replace(/InsertAfterMe/g, "InsertAfterMe " + toAppend);

Comment: I am just replacing `InsertAfterMe` in the string with `InsertAfterMe ` + the new string.

Comment: Incorrect answers tend to get down voted. Maybe you should have tested it first... or maybe you shouldn't just do all the work for the OP

Comment: @musefan have you checked it? Try clicking on Run code snippet, it will show you an alert.

Comment: @AmanGupta i have even reduced the code and it is doable with a for-loop.

Comment: I tested the original answer that I downvoted... im too busy to re-review and change my mind. Maybe next time you shouldn't be so quick to post code

Comment: @musefan can you tell me why it is even more wrong? And what does even more wrong means? And i think i edited it two time, every one was different and every one was working. Everytime i was just trying to make it short sweet and efficient, whats wrong with you?

Comment: @void:  *Try clicking on Run code snippet, it will show you an alert* (and all versions were wrong, you should pay more attention to the requirements)

Comment: @void sorry but the new update doesnt give correct output, it concate the list value after s1 and s2